# Is it okay to use a Data object from multiple threads simultaneously?

Tags: ios

Apple’s File System Programming Guide says this about NSData:

“Most of the Foundation objects you use to read and write file data can be used from any single thread but should not be used from multiple threads simultaneously.” https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

I have a download task whose completion handler runs on the main queue. This completion handler will dispatch the execution of a client’s ch to the main queue, and then dispatch a block of work to a background serial queue.

The client ch receives the Data object, and will likely create a UIImage from it. Whilst the block that was dispatched to a background queue will attempt to write the Data object to disk.

The client ch and the block of work for the background queue may run simultaneously, and they’re both ‘using’ the Data object. Should I prevent this simultaneous usage or is it okay?

Comment: `Data` in swift is a struct and structs are pass-by value/copy.. so it's fine anyway.. for NSData which is a class type, it's a different story.. In any case, as long as you aren't changing the Data in any way (IE: via UnsafePointer, etc..) then you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon. I was unsure, despite data being a struct. The confusion was because I'd been learning C recently, so I was thinking maybe the data was stored in the struct as a pointer, and that a copied Data would have copied pointers, so point to the same underlying data on the heap, and have the same position pointer, hence the concern that reading and writing at the same time would mess things up. But I was mixing up C struct and swift struct.